# Sidebar subfolder: Sort by alphabet by not by capitalisation

Tags: sublime-text-2, sublime-text

It's every time confuse me that in sublime-text at sidebar subfolders sort like:

```
Folder5
Folder8
folder1
folder7
```

How to force sublime-text to ignore letters case and sort subfolders like this:

```
folder1
Folder5
folder7
Folder8
```

?

Thanks.